# How to get accurate info on a device from solely the bluetooth address?

Tags: bluetooth

I am looking to be able to scan bluetooth addresses around me, and then get info on the devices from the address (i.e. if its a phone/speaker, or maybe if there is a public registry of device addresses).

I found https://www.macvendorlookup.com/, but when I put my phone's bluetooth address I get 'Bluberi Gaming Technologies Inc', which as far as I can find has nothing to do with my phone.

How can I get accurate info on a device from the Bluetooth address?

Comment: Yes, you can get the device type by its MAC. For classic Bluetooth devices look for Class Of Device (COD) values. For LE devices look for LE Appearance values.

Comment: It looks like you *got* info, you just didn't get the info you expected. So, I'm not sure how to answer your question.

Comment: @schroeder It doesn't seem to be correct - so I am wondering how to get correct info on the device.

Comment: Right, that's what I said. You've asked for how to get info, but you've got it. You want to know why this info is incorrect. That's an easier problem to look up: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/200474/mac-randomization-for-bluetooth

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Your phone randomises its address.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get information solely from the mac-address, the information in the MAC-vendor table is what you get.

If you want to scan what is around you and get a bit more info, then (on Linux), you could do:

```
bluetoothctl scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 7C:B2:7D:86:E1:CD Discovering: yes
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 bluetoothctl scan on

$ bg
$bluetoothctl devices
Device 50:C2:53:CE:25:2E Jabra Evolve2 Buds
Device F0:51:76:16:25:53 Alcatel 1SE
```